# Is it possible to find or match two names which has different special characters django

Tags: python, django, unicode, localization, special-characters

I am trying to populate cities in a state using OpenstreetMaps API to my django application. The database was populated with some cities already.
I am facing duplicate data issue since the name in cities sometime has special characters in it.

For example in country `Turkey`, The state `Bursa` has city `Gursu`.
My database has a city object with name `Gürsu`.
And the city name from Openstreet Map API is `Gürsü`.
I am trying to find a solution to match existing city with special character name and update it if it exists. So that I can avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The solution involving [unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode) is to match text according to UAX#10. You can do that in the database or in Python (possibly using PyICU). Here's some short code demonstrating:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
use Unicode::Collate qw();

my $c = Unicode::Collate->new(normalization => undef, level => 1);
my @g = qw(Gursu Gürsu Gursü Gürsü);

for my $o (@g) {
    for my $i (@g) {
        say "$i matches $o" if -1 != $c->index($o, $i, 0);
    }
}

__END__
Gursu matches Gursu
Gürsu matches Gursu
Gursü matches Gursu
Gürsü matches Gursu
Gursu matches Gürsu
Gürsu matches Gürsu
Gursü matches Gürsu
Gürsü matches Gürsu
Gursu matches Gursü
Gürsu matches Gursü
Gursü matches Gursü
Gürsü matches Gursü
Gursu matches Gürsü
Gürsu matches Gürsü
Gursü matches Gürsü
Gürsü matches Gürsü
```

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: @SudheerK, it's Perl.

Answer (score 0):

First of all they are not same they have different ASCII values.
But if you want to match `ü` with `u`
You need to work a bit for this you group the similar characters you think in a list like this is rough solution you can modify accordingly

```
import difflib
similar_groups=[['ü','u']] #add similar special characters here
country = 'Gursu'
country_b = 'Gürsü'
output_list = list(set([li[-1:] for li in difflib.ndiff(country, country_b) if li[0] != ' ']))
match=False #keep false for match found
print(output_list)
for val in similar_groups:
    if(sorted(output_list)==sorted(val)):
        match=True
    else:
        match=False

if match:
    print("Equal")
    #update or skip your stuff here
```

Comment: This is not practical since I am not sure which characters will be present. This is not the only case for ü